# Third party API call through Firebase Cloud functions ( with Blaze plan). React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use a Firebase cloud function to make an axios get request to a 3rd party API (Yelp). From what i read so far on related questions, other devs ran into similar issues mostly because they were on the **spark** plan, or didn't enable cors. I myself am currently on the **Blaze** plan.

Here is a breakdown of the issue:

**-Using:** React/Redux

**-steps:**

1-I wrote a function in my actions file (/actions/index), that makes an axios call to the firebase cloud function

```js
/*actions/index.js*/
import { dbConfig } from "../config/firebase";
import { LOGIN, LOAD_USERS, LOAD_ACTIVITIES, SEARCH_VENUE, RETRIEVEMATCH, SAVE_VENUE } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";


export const searchActivities = (search) => async(dispatch) => {
  /*call to cloud function*/
  axios.get("https://us-central1-we-party-210101.cloudfunctions.net/searchActivities", {headers:{ Authorization: `Bearer ${dbConfig.apiKey}`}})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(" search venue res: ", res.data);
    dispatch({
      type: SEARCH_VENUE,
      payload: res.data
    })
  })
  .catch( e => {
    console.log("searchActivities error: ", e);
  })
}
```

2-In the cloud function (/functions/index), I enable **cors** , add my Yelp api token as an authorization header and make the get request.

```js
/*/functions/index.js*/
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
var axios = require('axios');
var tokens = require('./functionSecrets');

// this function works fine when called the exact same way as the one below
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log("Hello World");
});

exports.searchActivities = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {
  // enable cors 
  cors(request, response, () => {
    // request to yelp api
    axios.get("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", {headers:{ Authorization: `bearer ${tokens.yelpKey}`}})
    .then(r => {
      console.log("Cloud yelp resp", r);
    })
    .catch( e => {
      console.log( "Cloud yelp error: ", e);
    })
  })

})
```

**-desired behavior:**

Yelp api response body is logged in my dev tools console. *NOTE:* I'm not worried about the dispatching in my actions file at this point since I'm not even getting the response in the first place.

**-Actual behavior:**

The request timesout after taking 6s to run. *NOTE:* that same request takes about 0.8 s on my local server. 
Below are the logs in my Firebase functions :

> searchActivities
>   Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

I'm fairly new to development in general, and I don't see what I'm missing here. I'm convinced it's a small thing and would love for anyone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**P.S**: I made sure to go through similar questions, but in case this still ends up being a duplicate, my apologies in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `searchActivities` Function must send a response back to the client to signal the end of its execution.

Otherwise the function executes until the 1 mins default timeout duration leading to a timeout.

You can [signal an end of the function execution](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#function_execution_timeline) with:

```
response.end()
```

Or otherwise send an appropriate response.

```
 cors(request, response, () => {
    // request to yelp api
    axios.get("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", {
      headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${tokens.yelpKey}`}
    })
    .then(r => {
      console.log("Cloud yelp resp", r);
      response.send(r.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log( "Cloud yelp error: ", e);
      response.sendStatus(500); // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    })
  })
```

Comment: Lol simple indeed. Thanks a lot:) There is no more timeout but now I get a **status 400**. it could be due to an issue on my side, but calling the api from my local server using the same get request (the axios request in our cloud function) works fine. I'll check if there are any limitations with yelp. Any extra suggestion would be welcome!

Comment: That should be happening with the request to Yelp. When you run `curl https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search -H "Authorization: Bearer <apikey>"` in your terminal, you see that there is a validation error that says that a location or latitude and a longitude should be specified.

Comment: That'sabsolutely right. I forgot to  copy paste the params from the call I made in my local server :(
Much apprecited!